# Python Loop isnt working properly

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x

I am trying to create a game where user enters letters until they guess the secret word, but for some reason my lists are not updating properly. 
Lets say the secret word is TOYS, if the user guesses T it displays T _ _ _ and then the user enters S but the word still displays T_ _ _ , adds S to the list of lettersInWord, and tells the user that S is NOT in the word. The loops are run in a while loop but the problem occurs inside the loop.

```
letter = input("Enter letter: ")
if letter not in enteredLetters:
    find = sentence.find(letter)
    if find == -1:
        print("Letter is not in word")
    else:
        newSentence = ""
        lettersInWord.append(letter)
        for letter in sentence:
            if letter in lettersInWord:
                newSentence = newSentence + letter 
            else:
                newSentence = newSentence + "_ "        
elif letter in enteredLetters:
    print ("The letter has been used")
print (newSentence)
enteredLetters.append(letter)
```

Comment: you didn't initialize `enteredLetters` (`enteredLetters = []`) or is just "cutted out"?

Comment: @DonCallisto: That clearly is not the problem here. You'd get exceptions in that case, that is not the case here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: was just asking because this could lead to a problem...

Comment: @DonCallisto I have initialized all variables outside loop, that is not a problem just the loop is

Comment: Is your sentence uppercased? Can you show us what is in the `sentence` variable?

Comment: @MartijnPieters any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the sentence variable just contains the word so it could be any word that is intialized so for the example sentence = "TOYS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rebinding `letter` in your loop:

```
for letter in sentence:
    if letter in lettersInWord:
```

`letter` is now a character in `sentence`, **not** the original user input. After that loop it'll still be bound to the last character in `sentence`, so `'S'`.

At the end of your code, it is *this* character (the last one in your sentence) that is added to `enteredLetters`:

```
enteredLetters.append(letter)
```

so `enteredLetters` now contains `['S']`, **not** `['T']`.

You'll need to pick a different name for the loop variable; `char` is a commonly used name:

```
for char in sentence:
    if char in lettersInWord:
        newSentence = newSentence + char 
    else:
        newSentence = newSentence + "_ "
```

Comment: how would I change the name could I just name it..i.. but then how would i incorporate the user input letter?

Comment: @novicecoder: I showed you how to rename the variable in the loop already. Keep the user input in `letter` still.

Comment: I did that I replaced letter with char but that doesnt work either because then it adds T to the lettersInWord twice and if I guess again it changes T_ _ _ to O O _ _ and adds O twice to the list

Comment: @novicecoder: You are still using `newSentence + letter` then, *not* `newSentence + char`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works but how come it still adds the letter into the list twice?

Comment: It doesn't; you are building `newSentence` solely with the user-entered letter, not the characters from `sentence`. Use my corrected loop properly. :-)

Comment: If you are using `newSentence = newSentence + letter` still, it'll use the entered character for each correctly guessed letter in the word. So if you guessed `O` correctly, after `T`, it'll print `OO_ _`. Then you guess `Y` correctly, it'll print `YYY_`. But if you use `newSentence = newSentence + char` instead, it'll print `TO_ _` and `TOY_` correctly.

Comment: I did exactly what your loop has but it still displays it twice. its okay as long as it works overall for right now im okay :). One last question:i have all of this in a while loop that exits out when the number of dashes = 0. if i have the number of dashes minus the number of times the letter occurs in the sentence so before loop: dashes = #of dashes so number of letters in word. Then in that else statment i count the occurrent of letters in sentence so dashesInSentence = sentence.count(letter) and at the end of the for loop i put dashes = dashes - dashsInSentence

Comment: You can also test if `newSentence == sentence`, once you have the placing of characters right.

Comment: (finishing my last comment) it doesnt exit out of the loop

Comment: Why not just use `dashesInSentence = newSentence.count('_')` instead?

Comment: hey I have a couple of more questions is there anyway I can email you the questions on here?

Comment: Sorry. I don't do email support; either post new questions here on Stack Overflow or use one of the (paid) pair programming / mentoring options I list in my profile.

Comment: can you please check this link out then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886045/python-interchanging-loop-wont-work